# Does Kusto support DEFAULT values for columns?

Tags: azure-data-explorer, kql

I have a table with 3 columns :

| ID | productId | customerId |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 5 | 1 |
| 2 | 4 | 1 |
| 3 | 5 | 1 |
| 4 | 4 | 1 |

I want to add a new column called ID_MOD and its value by default will be ID%X (X is a number).
Expected result for X=3 :

| ID | productId | customerId | ID_MOD |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 5 | 1 | 1 |
| 2 | 4 | 1 | 2 |
| 3 | 5 | 1 | 0 |
| 4 | 4 | 1 | 1 |

I have X instances of my app and I want each instance to query specific ID_MOD values(0/1/2.../X-1).

Is it possible to use default values for columns? If it is, can the default value be calculated based on other columns ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

what you can do is [create a stored function](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/data-explorer/kusto/management/create-alter-function) that receives `x` as an input parameter, and extends your table with a calculated column (at query time).

For example:

```
.create-or-alter function FunctionName(x:int)
{
    TableName
    | extend ID_MOD = ID % x
}
```

If you decide `x` always has the same value and shouldn't be parameter, you can name the function using the same name as the table, and it will 'hide' the original table.

If the logic of calculating the extended column is well-defined in advance, you can invoke it at ingestion time, using an [update policy](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/data-explorer/kusto/management/updatepolicy)

Comment: Is there any way to do it not during query time ? Feels like a better approach will be just to calc the ID_MOD before the ingestion to Kusto (which I also dont actually like..)

Comment: If the logic of calculating the extended column is well-defined in advance, you can invoke it at ingestion time, using an update policy: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/data-explorer/kusto/management/updatepolicy

Comment: Seems like the update policy is a better solution that suits the problem. Thanks for the help ! Can you please add it to the answer ?